# VLC virtual memory problem

Tags: kubuntu, vlc, ram

The laptop has Kubuntu 20.04.1 installed and 4 GB RAM memory and `VLC` version 3.0.11 installed via snap. After watching several MP4 videos with `VLC` the virtual memory increased to 2,6 GB RAM from 4 GB RAM. After i close the `VLC` the virtual memory remained with all the processes of `VLC` active filling the memory almost full. I restarted the laptop and opened the `VLC` again and as a result i had a virtual memory of 710 MB RAM from 4 GB RAM.

My question is why after i closed `VLC` the processes remained active in the virtual memory requiring a restart to close them ?

after close `VLC`
[image]

after restart
[image]

`VLC` installed via apt. I found the problem that causes other MP4 files to not open in `VLC` and `VLC` processes to remain active in virtual memory as a result of scrolling before a video and exiting `VLC` before the video ends. If i let the video run to the end and then close `VLC` there is no problem.
Is there any solution for this problem in `VLC` ?

after scrolling before a video in `VLC` and stopped before the end

[image]

Comment: When i listen to MP3 files with `VLC` , after i close them the `VLC` processes in the virtual memory also close. Why for MP4 files the `VLC` processes do not close automatically after closing `VLC` ?

Comment: Does this problem exist if you install VLC via apt and not as a snap?

Comment: @KGIII i uninstalled VLC via apt because after playing a few videos it didn't open at all i don't know why.

Comment: It may be worth trying to resolve that issue than to use a snap. Snaps have all sorts of issues with things like limited permissions causing odd behavior/bugs. If you open VLC from the terminal and then try to play those videos, it *may* throw errors that let you find the solution. There are also tons of VLC tutorials about all sorts of media types. You can check under 'tools' to find things like media and codec information (while attempting to play those files) as well.

Comment: Ok i will try to do that.

Comment: @KGIII i installed `mpv` media player and as a result there are no more errors or to fill virtual memory almost completely. I think that in `VLC` there would be a problem with the codecs because there is an error in the main decoder that fills the virtual memory with vlc processes that normally should be closed automatically at the end of a video. Why does `mpv` work ok and `VLC` doesn't ? Other codecs are used in `mpv` ?

Comment: If you want, you can write that up as an answer and then accept it. It's an acceptable answer to say, "I just used different software because of ____ and the end result is ____." That way, people with your problem will be aware that changing software is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubuntu 20.04.1
integrated video card AMD STONEY R2
4 GB RAM DDR4

I used a different software because in `VLC` there is a problem with the main decoder that gives errors when you close a video before the end. As a result the VLC process remains in the virtual memory and if you open more videos and close them before the end the VLC processes do not close automatically causing the virtual memory to be filled almost completely requiring a restart to close them.
I installed `mpv` media player and although it has no options except for arranging the window you can play MP4 files without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that appears to work on [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1876505)

> Mohammad Reza Moghaddasi (vision-183) wrote on 2020-05-11:    #3
>
> Change the video output to XCB & it closes properly .
> I set it on XCB & then revert it to automatic & WOW it now closes properly as well.

> Taygun Bulmus (bulmust) wrote on 2021-01-19:  #4
>
> Thanks Mohammad Reza Moghaddasi. Thats work for me. The solution steps are following:
>
> **Tools -> Preferences -> Video (tab) -> Output -> XVideo output (XCB)**